# Is is possible to push value to default Sublime text config?

Tags: sublimetext, sublimetext3

In Default\Preferences.sublime-setting I have

```
"folder_exclude_patterns": [".svn", ".git", ".hg", "CVS"],
```

I want to write in User\Preferences.sublime-setting or project-name.sublime-settings something like

```
"folder_exclude_patterns" += [".idea", ".sbt"]
```

Which makes much more sense when copying and extending original array.

Is it possible in some way?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can modify `project-name.sublime-settings` with the following (this will extend  `folder_exclude_patterns` from `User\Preferences.sublime-settings`):

```
{
    "folders":
    [
        {
            "path": ".",
            "folder_exclude_patterns": [".idea", ".sbt"]
        }
    ]
}
```

The syntax you were trying to use is not a valid [JSON](http://json.org/), the format that Sublime Text uses to store it's settings.

Comment: It really works, I just don't understand why. Shouldn't it **replace** values in `User\Preferences.sublime-settings` instead?

Comment: @roma yes, it will replace those values. You'll need to put **all** desired values in your array.

Comment: Values from `project-name.sublime-settings` **do** add to values from `User\Preferences.sublime-settings`(checked). It was just rather unexpected behaviour.